# Laravel: query a many to many relationship and scape the rows in first table if condition is not true in the second table

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, laravel-query-builder, eloquent-relationship

I have two tables `posts` and `employees` they have many to many relationship.

Now I want to query all the posts where in pivot table 'user_id' is `logedin user` and `status` is `Accepted`;

there is my query

```
public function accepted()
{
    $posts = Post::with(['employees' => function ($q) {
            $q->wherePivot('status', 'Accepted')
                ->where('user_id', Auth::id());
        }])
        ->with('address', 'service')
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
        ->paginate(10);

    return response()->json($posts);
}
```

If you look at below image, all the posts returned, even if the condition in pivot table is not true.

[image]

In the above image; there are two rows, in first row `employees []` is empty which I do not want to be returned. and the second row must only be returned because conditions in 'employees.pivot' true.

I hope explained it well.

Answer (score 1):

Passing a Closure to `with` specifies which related models (`Employee`) to load, but does nothing to filter the model you're querying (`Post`).

To make add that filter, you need to use `whereHas(relation, Closure)`

```php
$posts = Post::query()
    ->whereHas('employee', function ($rel) {
        $rel->where('your_pivot_table_name.status', 'Accepted')
            ->where('user_id', Auth::id());
    })
    ->with([
        'address',
        'service',
        'employees' => function ($rel) {
            $rel->wherePivot('status', 'Accepted')
                ->where('user_id', Auth::id());
        }
    ])
    ->orderByDesc('created_at')
    ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: I get this error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pivot' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `posts` where exists (select * from `employees` inner join `employee_post` on `employees`.`id` = `employee_post`.`employee_id` where `posts`.`id` = `employee_post`.`post_id` and `pivot` = status and `user_id` = 4))" . in the first query there is employees not employee but anyway I get pivot not found column.

Comment: I did some research and yes, the method `wherePivot` doesn't work with whereHas. Instead, you can pass in the column directly (preferrably with the full table name). I'll edit my answer